# Python & URLLIB2 - Request webpage but don't wait for response

Tags: python, urllib2

In python, how would I go about making a http request but not waiting for a response. I don't care about getting any data back, I just need to server to register a page request.

Right now I use this code:

```
urllib2.urlopen("COOL WEBSITE")
```

But obviously this pauses the script until a a response is returned, I just want to fire off a request and move on.

How would I do this?

Comment: As a hint for the future: Please add the needed python version (e.g. `python-2.7` or `python-3.x`) to the flags so we know what python version you request (there are multiple differences between those versions)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you want here is called **Threading** or **Asynchronous**.

**Threading**:

- Wrap the call to `urllib2.urlopen()` in a `threading.Thread()`

Example:

```
from threading import Thread

def open_website(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen(url)

Thread(target=open_website, args=["http://google.com"]).start()
```

**Asynchronous:**

- Unfortunately there is no standard way of doing this in the Python standard library.

Use the [requests](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) library which has this support.

Example:

```
from requests import async

async.get("http://google.com")
```

There is also a 3rd option using the [restclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/restclient/) library which has
builtin (*has for some time*) **Asynchronous** support:

```
from restclient import GET

res = GET("http://google.com", async=True, resp=True)
```

Comment: For future reference, `requests.async` has been removed in favor of [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests)

Answer (score 3):

Use thread:

```
import threading

threading.Thread(target=urllib.urlopen, args=('COOL WEBSITE',)).start()
```

Don't forget `args` argument should be tuple. That's why there's trailing `,`.

Comment: Simple one-liner with Python standard libs and no extra function - I like this!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with requests library as follows

```
import requests
try:
    requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/",timeout=10)
except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: #this confirms you that the request has reached server
    do_something
except:
    print "unable to reach server"
    raise
```

from the above code you can send async requests without getting response. Specify timeout according to your need. if not it will not time out.

Comment: This is't an async request. It's merely a request with a timeout.

Comment: Yeah but there is no async option in requests so I came up with this hack. That’s why I’ve used dead timeout exception for confirmation. If we use threads as mentioned in one of the answers program may end but thread may still wait for response.

Answer (score 1):

[gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) may be a proper choice.

First patch socket:

```
import gevent
import gevent.monkey
monkey.patch_socket()
monkey.patch_ssl()
```

Then use `gevent.spawn()` to encapulate your requests to generate greenlets. It will not block the main thread and be very fast!

Here's a simple [tutorial](http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/).